# wamp apache 2.4.9 not started after adding virtual host in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, symfony, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am using wamp (php v 5.5.12, apache v 2.4.9). When I start the apache server the icon becomes green as if everything is fine. I can access to all services with no problem. When I try to add a virtual host to configure in httpd.conf for my symfony project apache will not restart.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\tuto\Symfony\web
    <Directory "C:\wamp\www\tuto\Symfony\web">
        DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
```

The server icon then stays in yellow instead of green and I can't access to localhost url. When I remove my config, everything becomes normal again. Please help me to understand how I can resolve this.

Comment: You are missing the ServerName parameter of VirtualHost. I believe this is required.

Comment: There is a line "ServerName localhost" just above <VirtualHost *:80> . Do you talk about that one ?

Comment: Yes, that should instead be inside the <VirtualHost></VirtualHost> section

Comment: A quick look at the Apache error log would tell you what's wrong too ;-)

Comment: It's solved, thank you guys : What I did :                                                                       1-Adding my conf in httpd-vhost.conf  with ServerName parameter "ServerName www.project.com"  inside <VirtualHost></VirtualHost> section as @skrilled said.                                                                         2-In the httpd.conf, Uncomment this line : "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"                                                                                              3-In the system file "hosts", I add "127.0.0.1 www.project.com"

Answer (score 0):

You have a single-quote at the end of:

```
</VirtualHost>`
```

Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the symfony 2  built in server . first undo any changes on your httpd.conf
open your cmd and do this:

```
cd C:\wamp\www\tuto\Symfony\web
```

next

```
php app/console server:run
```

now try this on your browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000
this is equal to : http://localhost/tuto/Symfony/web/app_dev.php

if you want to start web server on your local ip use this

```
php app/console server:run yourIP:port
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, thank you guys !
 What I did :

1-Adding my conf in httpd-vhost.conf with ServerName parameter 
`ServerName www.project.com` inside  section as @skrilled said.

2-In the httpd.conf, Uncomment this line : `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

3-In the system file "hosts", I added this line : `127.0.0.1 www.project.com`